# Overloading function doesn't work with complex

Tags: c++, templates

I have written this simple C++ code to swap any two variables. It works for int and double, but doesn't work for complex numbers, any idea why?

```
#include <iostream>  
#include <complex>  

using std::cout; 
using std::endl; 
using std::complex; 

template <class T>

inline void swap(T& d, T& s)
{
    T temp = d;
    d = s;
    s = temp;
}


int main()
{
   int m=5, n=10;
   double x=5.3, y=10.6;
   complex<double> r(2.4, 3.5), s(3.4, 6.7);

   cout << "inputs:  " << m << " , " << n << endl;
   swap(m, n);
   cout << "outputs: " << m << " , " << n << endl;

   cout << "double inputs:  " << x << " , " << y << endl;
   swap(x, y);
   cout << "double outputs: " << x << " , " << y << endl;

   cout << "complex inputs:  " << r << " , " << s << endl;
   swap(r, s);
   cout << "complex outputs: " << r << " , " << s << endl;
}
```

This is the error:

```
g++ 02.swap.template.cpp -o c.out.02
02.swap.template.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
02.swap.template.cpp:37:13: error: call of overloaded ‘swap(std::complex<double>&, std::complex<double>&)’ is ambiguous
02.swap.template.cpp:37:13: note: candidates are:
02.swap.template.cpp:13:13: note: void swap(T&, T&) [with T = std::complex<double>]
/usr/include/c++/4.6/bits/move.h:122:5: note: void std::swap(_Tp&, _Tp&) [with _Tp = std::complex<double>]
```

Comment: There's already a `std::swap`. Use that. In your case, it's because of ADL.

Comment: I am trying to learn the use of template, and this is an example from coursera lectures! So, why it doesn't work

Comment: @chris: Are you sure about this? ADL should not introduce ambiguities, since it's only considered *after* ordinary lookup has failed.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I was under the impression that lookup employed ADL alongside other lookup. I could be wrong, but I don't know why there would be ambiguity here then.

Comment: @VahidMir try just renaming your function. The compiler's error message is saying that there's a name conflict with `std::swap`.

Comment: Well, you can prevent ADL with parentheses: `(swap)(r, s);` But I still don't fully understand why ADL gets in the way.

Comment: @KerrekSB, I think the most relevant part is § 3.4.2 /3.

Comment: @chris: Yep, found it. I posted it as an answer.

Comment: Argument Dependent Lookup (ADL) kicks in because there is no ordinary, i.e. non-template, `swap` -- user defined `swap` and `std::swap` are both templated. The error does not show up for `int` and `double` because `std::` is not looked up, per standard draft n1905 3.4.2: "— If T is a fundamental type, its associated sets of namespaces and classes are both empty."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

name conflit, changing to ::swap solves the issue.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that *argument-dependent lookup* is applied because you are calling a function *template*. If you had a plain function, there would be no ambiguity:

```
#include <complex>

void swap(complex<double> & d, complex<double> & s)
{
    complex<double> temp = d;
    d = s;
    s = temp;
}


int main()
{
   std::complex<double> r(2.4, 3.5), s(3.4, 6.7);
   swap(r, s);
}
```

This is because of C++11 3.4.2:

> Let *X* be the lookup set produced by unqualified lookup (3.4.1) and let *Y* be the lookup set produced by argument dependent lookup (defined as follows). If *X* contains
>
> — a declaration of a class member, or
>
> — a block-scope function declaration that is not a using-declaration, or
>
> — a declaration that is neither a function or a function template
>
> then *Y* is empty. Otherwise *Y* is the set of declarations found in the namespaces associated with the argument types as described below. The set of declarations found by the lookup of the name is the union of *X* and *Y*.

In the above case, *X* contains a block-scope function declaration.

However, if the unqualified lookup finds the function *template* you provided, then the ADL rules say that the argument-dependent lookup set is also considered. Since `std::complex<double>` lives in the `std` namespace, this namespace is also searched for the name `swap`, which already exists (by 20.2.2).

You can prevent argument-dependent lookup by wrapping the function name in parentheses:

```
(swap)(r, s);
```

This way, only the unqualified lookup is considered.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler says it is confused because of two functions : yours and the standard std::swap. It consider std::swap too because std::complex is member of std::namespace, it's calling Argument Dependant Lookup. If you want to explicitly test your swap, you can use :: scope resolution operator, ie ::swap instead of swap. It will make another kind of lookup : Qualified Name Lookup solving the ambiguity.

Nonetheless, std::swap works well and do the job, except as exercise, include utility standard header, make a using std::swap, and it will work fine :

```
#include<utility>

//before needed (closest)
using std::swap;
swap(/*arguments*/);
```

Comment: `std::swap` is in `<algorithm>` as well. It changed with C++11 (your answer is right for the most recent standard).